# Is it possible to call an API action without using any kind of script?

Tags: api, asp.net-mvc-4

I'd like to use APIs in a web application I'm building with Visual Studio.
I am studing how APIs work and I followed [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) tutorial by asp.net.

The last step od this tutorial teaches me how to create the view and it uses jQuery `getJSON` function to send an AJAX request.

```
<script>
    var apiUrl = 'api/products';

    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Send an AJAX request
        $.getJSON(apiUrl)
            .done(function (data) {
                // On success, 'data' contains a list of products.
                $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                    // Add a list item for the product.
                    $('<li>', { text: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($('#products'));
                });
            });
    });

    function formatItem(item) {
        return item.Name + ': $' + item.Price;
    }

    function find() {
        var id = $('#prodId').val();
        $.getJSON(apiUrl + '/' + id)
            .done(function (data) {
                $('#product').text(formatItem(data));
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                $('#product').text('Error: ' + err);
            });
    }
</script>
```

And, if I'm right, this script build the urls I want to call.
While the urls are defined by my ApiController, isn't it?

Well, what should I do if I wouldn't want to use jQuery? Could I replace it with a generic `Url.Action`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script doesn't just build the URIs, it calls them using AJAX and builds HTML based on the data it receives.

`$.getJSON` calls your API methods via AJAX (i.e., the browser calls the API methods) and the API methods return data in JSON format. The `done` and `fail` functions of the `$.getJSON` calls then process the results.

And why would you not want to use jQuery? Although it takes some time to learn, it definitely makes your development life easier!

Comment: Since I have some actions that operate in the back-end of my application, I thought that, in order to improve the security, it was not completely sure to use jQuery, that is located in the front-end, to call theese actions.  
I was just wondering if there were different ways to do that.